# Tiny worms found inside my house

Tags: species-identification

I noticed spider cob hanging of my light bulb. That spider web was full of moving creatures. I quickly removed them and threw in the big. Wanted to find out what could that possibly be. I opened up light bulb and no traces to the ceiling. I found hundreds of them fallen on the floor, some where still moving. I do not have a good quality picture, but I have taken a video of it. Would anyone be able to identify? I live in Australia QLD, i think this could have been seeded by some fly?[image]